# Only allow json to be edited via my program

Tags: javascript, json, security, encryption, electron

I am creating a local desktop app in electron using javascript where I want to log each number a user chooses using my app and add that number to a json file. But I only want the app to be able to update the json, not the user.

So for example, there is a textbox that says choose a number, the user types a number (837) and clicks submit. Now I want to have the program store this number along with all the other numbers previously submitted to an existing json file, like:

```
{"Numbers":473,392,299,837"}
```

Im not a expert but I know I can encrypt the data so the user couldn't edit it, but then once its run through the program it will have to be decrypted so the user could easily edit the json after, correct?

Also I have read I could hash the file to prove its the original context, but as i need the program to edit the json this will not be possible as the hash would change.

Is it even possible to do this? I need a way the user cannot edit the data but the program can.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is not possible. The file, and the modification of it, take place on the users computer.  They control their computer and the information on it. Encrypting the file doesn't help, since the encryption key is present in your code/binary.

The solution, the only solution, is to store the numbers on a server and expose an API that the client can make requests to.